# Using where expression with not in operator in SAS

Tags: sas, where-clause

I have a database table, called CityData, which is queried using SAS through an ODBC. The table has a column, City, which has Missing/Null values. The following data step in SAS does not give the expected results -

```
Data New;
set CityData;
where pop> 10000 and City not in ('Mumbai')
run;
```

The above code excludes Null values from the output dataset. The following code, however, works as expected

```
Data New;
set CityData;
where pop > 10000 and (City not in ('Mumbai') or City is Null);
run;
```

Why? I am using a Windows SAS version 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the way the DBMS evaluates nulls.  The libname engine sends your `where` statement back via implicit pass-through, and this evaluates to:

```
where pop> 10000 and City ne 'Mumbai'
```

`null <> 'Mumbai'` = null, hence nothing returned.

You are also missing a semicolon from your where statement.

```
Data New;
set CityData;
where pop> 10000 and City not in ('Mumbai'); 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that the `where` statements are interpreted by the DBMS. AFAIK, if the `CityData` data was a native SAS dataset, then the condition `missing <> 'Mumbai'` would evaluate to True, so an ODBC data is not exactly the same as SAS dataset from a code perspective. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: correct - it's something to watch out for.  More info here:  http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Be_Aware_of_Implicit_Pass-Through